# Adding operations on Model without adding code to Model

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Say i have an hierarchy of `Shape` objects, each has its own data (polyline has list of vertices, circle has a center and radius, etc).

I want to be able to perform operations on each shape, such as Draw, Snap to some point, split to two shapes at a specific point, etc.

One way to do it is to add a method to Shape interface for each operation. However, in that case i will have to modify my model interface every time a new operation is added. It does not sound correct to me. I thought of the following solution and would like to here your opinion or other solutions.

---

I will add an interface of ShapeOperationsFactory and the following method to Shape interface:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ShapeOperationFactory* createShapeOperationsFactory() = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual ShapeOperationsFactory* createShapeOperationsFactor();
};

ShapeOperationsFactory* Circle::createShapeOperationsFactory()
{
    return new CircleShapeOperationsFactory();
}
```

ShapeOperationsFactory will be able to create a set of operations classes that are specific for the shape:

```
class ShapeOperationsFactory
{
public:
    virtual ShapeDrawer* createDrawer() = 0;
    virtual ShapeSnapper* createSnapper() = 0;
    virtual ShapeSplitter* createSplitter() = 0;
};

class CircleShapeOperationsFactory : public ShapeOperationsFactory
{
public:
    virtual ShapeDrawer* createDrawer();
    virtual ShapeSnapper* createSnapper();
    virtual ShapeSplitter* createSplitter();
}

ShapeDrawer* CircleShapeOperationsFactory::createDrawer()
{
    return new CircleShapeDrawer();
}

ShapeSnapper* CircleShapeOperationsFactory::createSnapper()
{
    return new CircleShapeSnapper();
}

ShapeSplitter* CircleShapeOperationsFactory::createSplitter()
{
    return new CircleShapeSplitter();
}
```

In this implementation the Shape interface will not change when new operations are added. For new shape i will need to implement a new operations factory and a class per operation. For new operations i will need to add a method to the operations factory class and a class implementing the operation for each shape.

Comment: I don't see how this factory thing is helping the problem.  If you want to add a new virtual operation (that is, something you can do when all you know is that the object is a `Shape`), every factory needs to add it to their `ShapeOperationsFactory`.  Furthermore, since the factories have no inheritance you've lost your OOP.  If you want to add operations to `Shape` and let all derived classes use this operation, then obviously all of the derived classes will have to implement it.  I think I may be missing the question here?

Comment: A factory for each shape inherits from the ShapeOperationsFactory class (I had a mistake in the code and i edited it). With these factories, i don't need to change the Shape and its inherited classes when new operations are added

Comment: But you do need to change `ShapeOperationFactory` and its derived stuff, so isn't this just postponing the issue?

Comment: I think it will help creating a much more modular system and i will not have to add many many methods to the Shape interface. It should generally be the model and performing heavy logic inside it seems incorrect. What do you think?

Comment: I am still not sure I understand your problem here, but this is my interpretation.  You have lots of derived classes for `Shape`, and the duty of `Shape` is very large.  As a result, there are a large number of virtual interface functions that would have to go into `Shape`, which also probably means that all derived classes must implement every new interface function.  There's nothing you can do to fix this, unless you mean to say that not all derived classes actually use a lot of the interface functions?

Comment: This is indeed my problem. I can't fix it in terms of amount of code or implementations i will need to write. However, i can make sure that Shape classes will not be very large and that their responsibility will be clear and precise.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just split up all of `Shape`'s responsibilities into precursor classes such as `ShapeOperationsFactory` and then have `Shape` just inherit these groups of interfaces?  Just to be sure, this is completely an organizational question and not anything functionally related?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you suggest that CircleShape would inherit from CircleSnapper and CircleDrawer, etc?

Comment: Let's say you have a group of functions that you want to be associated with each other.  For instance, the `drawer`, `snapper`, and `splitter` stuff all falls under one category of functions.  You package these together into a class that could be called `Operations` or something. `Shape` inherits from `Operations` and whatever other groups of operations you want, and `Circle` just inherits from `Shape` as normal.  Now, `Circle` has inherited all functionality, and references to it can be cast to any subgroup of functions that you may need (or just directly used, whatever floats your boat).

Answer (score 0):

Making your classes more modular by creating an Operator class I think is great, but this is not really a factory. Factory usually involved creating an object base on some message, for example on a unserialization process.

For your case you could have an Operator member in your base class and in the constructor of your derived class you assign that member to the appropriate Operator derived class.

Comment: I think you could refer to it as an abstract factory, similar to what described in wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern. In my design, each shape implements a method that returns a class that is responsible to create various operation classes. I believe this class can be called a factory

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use the [visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). The purpose of this design pattern :

> the visitor design pattern is a way of separating an algorithm from an object structure on which it operates. A practical result of this separation is the ability to **add new operations to existing object structures without modifying those structures**. It is one way to follow the open/closed principle.

The principle is simple:

You create a visitor class:

```
class Visitor
{
  public:
    virtual void visit(Circle*) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Polyline*) = 0;
    ...
};
```

You add this method to `Shape`:

```
virtual void accept(class Visitor*) = 0;
```

Then you implements this method in each `Shape` sub class.

```
void Circle::accept(Visitor *v)
{
    v->visit(this);
}
```

And then you have to create one visitor per operation:

```
class Drawer: public Visitor
{
  public:
    Drawer()
    {
    }
    void visit(Circle* c)
    {
        drawCircle(c);
    }
    void visit(Polyline*p)
    {
        drawPolyline(p);
    }
    ...
};
```

You could also delegate each visit method to a service: (`visit(Circle* c)` to a `CircleDrawer`).

```
    void visit(Circle* c)
    {
        circleDrawer->draw(c);
    }
    void visit(Polyline*p)
    {
        polylineDrawer->draw(p);
    }
```

If you want to add an operation, you will have to create a new visitor sub class.

If you want to add a shape, you will have to add a new method on each visitor.

---

The visitor collaborare really well with the composite design pattern (heavily use in gui programming). The visitor pattern can be used in addition with the composite pattern. The object structure can be a composite structure. In this case in the implementation of the accept method of the composite object the accept methods of the component object has to be invoked.

---

Note:
I am not a c++ programmer, feel free to edit and make the code syntactically correct.

Comment: Yes, it would also work pretty well. However, my concern here is that if i will have many shapes, each such visitor will have a lot of code.

Comment: You are right, this is why i propose to delegate each visit method to a specific service. Furthermore, it could be interesting to have some centralized logic in some case (drawing for example).

Comment: I think that such design is eventually very similar to my suggestion.

Comment: You are missing an important point. The visitor allows to add new operations without any modification on the `Shape` layer.

Comment: The is not exactly correct. In the visitor pattern you will have to add functions in each shape for new operation (that would perform visit() on the visitor). In my design new operations are added without any change to the Shape layer at all

Comment: Because you are considering that your `ShapeOperationsFactory` is not part of the shape layer. This is wrong for me since your shape depends on this factory. With the visitor pattern, you could implement a new operation by adding a new Visitor implementaion ; leaving the shape layer unchanged.

Comment: So i maintain my opinion. Adding a new operation have no impact on the shape layer.

Comment: The ShapeOperationsFactory is not part of the Shape layer - it is implemented once and any change to the factory or the operations does not affect the shapes at all. The visitor, although is also a good solution, require a new method to be added to the Shape layer for each new operation. This means the the shape layer is not unchanged

Comment: I think you don't understand how the visitor pattern works. You ONLY need to implement one accept method on each shape. Adding an operation need ONLY to add a visitor sub class

Comment: The Shape depends on the ShapeOperationFactory. If you are working on a library, you can't add an operation externnaly.

Comment: OK, i missed the way you implemented the visitor pattern. Yes, in this implementation you are correct that it does not depend on anything.

Comment: However, it does mean that each visitor must have a method for each shape even if it delegates the behavior to other classes. Also, what if the operations receive parameters and each operation has different parameters - if complicates the visitor the pattern.

Comment: You are right. With your solution adding an operation induce a modification of the api, but adding a shape induce a modification. With the visitor it is the inverse. Visitor must be used if the visited hierarchy is quite stable. Design is often a matter of tradeoff. If you need parameters, you have to inject them at visitor construction.